# custom event trigger in google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Every time i create a custom trigger event it doesn't get fire. Can anybody please what may be the reason. I have created 'gacustomevent'custom triggerand have name it 'gaevent' but the event is not getting fired. Iwant to use the event in the dataLayer to capture the value. Any advice on how to get issue resolve

Answer (score 15):

It's a bit unclear from your question how you set this up. It should look like this:

```
dataLayer.push({
   'event':'myEvent'
})
```

(this assumes that the dataLayer is already initialized).

In GTM you go to the "variables" section. In the boxes with the predefined variables you hit the checkbox in front of "event". Now you're ready to use your custom event in a trigger.

Go to "trigger", select new -> custom event. In the event name box you enter "myEvent" (as per my example, substitute with your own value).

The custom event only works when there is a key/value pair in the dataLayer where the key is "event" (that's kind of a 'reserved word' in GTM). The event name is always the value for that key.

Comment: Is it normal to not see any requests made in the network tab? My `dataLayer` exists, I do the push, but there's no activity in the network tab of the dev toolbar.

Comment: You will only see things in the network tab if you trigger a tag that makes requests. Changes to the datalayer will not, by themselves, be visible in the network tab.

Comment: But then how do the events get to google? Sorry, I'm not familiar with how GTM works (even though I've read about it -- I'm just not a marketing man). I'm only used to the old GA, which made a web request to google as soon as you triggered an event.

Comment: "Event" in GTM is not the same as event tracking in Google (although you can trigger Analytics event tracking via a GTM event).  The GTM event basically tells GTM that something happened (and it updates the internal state of the dataLayer). Then you create a GA tag for event tracking and a trigger based on the custom event, and only at this point you will see something happen in the network tab.

Comment: I think the GTM rules that are configured in the admin, are loaded into the client at runtime. So a dataLayer push needs to be evaluated on the client to decide what todo.