# How to tag an element in the DOM that only appears after another event?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a button that enables a javascript that builds into the DOM a few more divs with classes.
As Google Tag loads right on the start of the page, when I click the mentioned button it doesn't recognize the element that is being added to the DOM from that button, even though it was tagged properly.

My question is how can I tag an element in the DOM that is dependent on another event, of which hasn't loaded yet into the DOM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GTM needs a ([custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427762/custom-event-trigger-in-google-tag-manager) or native) event to update its internal data model. "Event" in this case does not mean a javascript event, it means a key/value pair with the key name "event" needs to be pushed to the dataLayer array. datalayer.push() is a custom implementation of the push method that observes the datalayer to see if a new event was sent.

Actually a click event is a "native" event in GTM provided you have enabled click variables in the variables section of the menu. I guess the reason that this does not help you is that the DOM elements are added only after the event.

So I suggest you look for the function that adds the DOM element and add a callback function; this callback pushes an event to the dataLayer after the DOM elements have been added. Then you trigger your tags on that custom event, and you should be able to access your new DOM nodes.

Comment: Excellent full depth answer, tagged as answer, thanks.